# Function tocheck a password within a database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm writing down the code for an Android Studio App, but when I test the function for check if the password is correct and matches in the db, the app crashes. I've isolated the problem within this following code. If I remove this function from the code, the app works perfectly.

```
 public String searchPass(String uname, String pass){
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query= "select uname, pass from" + TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(query, null);
    String a, b;
    b="not found";
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            a= cursor.getString(0);
            if(a.equals(uname)){
                b=cursor.getString(1);
                break;
            }
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return b;
}
```

Comment: Try changing `"select uname, pass from"` to `"select uname, pass from "` (i.e. add a space after **from**). If that doesn't resolve the issue then edit your question to include the stack-trace.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that there will be an SQL syntax error due to a space missing between the FROM keyword and the table name.

To fix the issue use :-

```
    String query= "select uname, pass from " + TABLE_NAME;
```